# How to test error case in golang with "entgo.io/ent"

Tags: go, testing, ent

I am writing go code in a project using ent,
and wondering if there are any ways to test specific error block thrown by `Save`.

Does anyone know good practice to do this?

test target code example
(from: [ent/examples/start/start.go](https://github.com/ent/ent/blob/55ed0508c7bfc3c3bd712e061bdc4b95a765208f/examples/start/start.go))

```golang
func CreateCars(ctx context.Context, client *ent.Client) (*ent.User, error) {
    tesla, err := client.Car.
        Create().
        SetModel("Tesla").
        SetRegisteredAt(time.Now()).
        Save(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed creating car: %w", err)
    }

    ford, err := client.Car.
        Create().
        SetModel("Ford").
        SetRegisteredAt(time.Now()).
        Save(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        // I want to test this block.
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed creating car: %w", err)
    }

    a8m, err := client.User.
        Create().
        SetAge(30).
        SetName("a8m").
        AddCars(tesla, ford).
        Save(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed creating user: %w", err)
    }

    return a8m, nil
}
```

test code example

```golang
t.Run("method returns error as expected", func(t *testing.T) {
    user, err := CreateCars(ctx, client)

    // test error message begin with "failed creating car:" here
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the *Save()* method throws an error, you may do something incorrect to the database. For example, set the same *Car.ID* manually and let it duplicate.